# return ajax post response

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

i need some help to understand this js / jquery - thing..

I`am not the best js scripter, but i want to lean something about it.

I want to create an rest-api, the backend with php is no problem, but now i have to script the frontend.

The interactive communication with the frontend i want to realize with jquery / ajax. After a few hours to trying to understand this function i ask you.

Actually verry simple i want to return the response of the $.post(...).done(..); function.

The code i´ve wrote:

```
      function apiCall($methode = '', $value = ''){
        return $.post(endpoint, {'apiKey': apiKey, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',async: false,dataType: "json"}).done(function (response){console.log('inner response: ' + response['status']);return response});
      }
```

The output in the console:

1.

```json
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"status\":\"ok\"}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "status": "ok"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
}
```

2. 

```
inner response: ok
```

My function call:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my-submit").click(function (){
            console.log((apiCall()))
        });
      });
```

How its possible to throw the return from the .done() function up to my `console.log((apiCall()))` call?

I´ve tried everything i know from other programming / script languages, global variables some other funciton calls, but nothing work. :(

EDIT:
I have to adress my return with the ````then``` argument. This works for me:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#domain-report-submit").click(function (){
            apiCall().then((data) => console.log(data['status']));
        });
      });
```

Comment: You can't have a value **now** when it won't exist until some time in the future.

Comment: Try changing the `async` to true. Also, since the ajax is a promise, await the apiCall()

Comment: @Quentin ithe thought I had also, but in the first output, so the function call in the log he has the output? The 1st output would then have to be null or something similar?

Comment: @AntonyMN no, same. I belive my problem is, that i dont know ho to address the result? Something like ```console.log((apiCall()['status']))``` dont work.

Comment: What I mean is, `console.log(await (apiCall()))`.

Don't forget to put the function in an async.

Comment: @AntonyMN doenst work to :( But if i use ```then``` it works. Thank you.